# Looping through array and returning results of each object in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I need some help with the following PS code:

```
$site1 = "www.site1.com"
$site2 = "www.site2.com"
$site3 = "www.site3.com"
$sites = $site1,$site2,$site3
$request = foreach ($site in $sites) {invoke-webrequest $site -method head}
if ($request.StatusCode -ne "200"){write-host "site is not working"}
```

The actual output of $request returns the headers of all 3 sites, so how do I get the exact site that failed the test?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
"www.site1.com","www.site2.com", "www.site3.com" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest $_ -Method Head

        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Site = $_
            StatusCode = $response.StatusCode
        }
    }
```

You can filter the output by appending the following after the last bracket:

```
| Where-Object StatusCode -ne 200
```